# FlywayException: Version may only contain 0..9 and . (dot). Invalid version: 1.....) at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.toBigInteger:271

Tags: kotlin, migration, flyway, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am building api with ktor, exposed and mysql. I am trying to use automated migration generation, but it throws an error.

so in src/main/db/migration/V1_create_users_table.kt

```
package db.migration

import com.coinypal.features.user.UsersTable
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.BaseJavaMigration
import org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.Context
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.SchemaUtils
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.transactions.transaction

class V1_create_users_table : BaseJavaMigration() {
    override fun migrate(context: Context?) {
        transaction{
            SchemaUtils.create(
                UsersTable
            )
        }
    }
}
```

in the start of the app I am running init from my DBFactory

```
package com.coinypal.config

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig
import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway
import org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Database
import javax.sql.DataSource

object DbFactory {
    fun init(pool: DataSource) {
        Database.connect(pool)
        runFlyway(pool)
    }

    fun init(dbProperties: Env.Datasource) {
        val pool = hikari(dbProperties)
        Database.connect(pool)
        runFlyway(pool)
    }

    private fun hikari(dbProperties: Env.Datasource): HikariDataSource {

        val hikariConfig = HikariConfig().apply {
            jdbcUrl = dbProperties.url
            username = dbProperties.username
            password = dbProperties.password
            driverClassName = dbProperties.driver
        }

        return HikariDataSource(hikariConfig)
    }

    private fun runFlyway(datasource: DataSource) {
        val flyway = Flyway.configure().dataSource(datasource).load()
        try {
            flyway.info()
            flyway.migrate()
        } catch (error: Exception) {
            throw error
        }
    }
}
```

my db dependencies look like this

```
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-core:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposed_version")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-java-time:$exposed_version") //exposed_version=0.38.2
    implementation("com.zaxxer:HikariCP:$hikariCp_version")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-core:$flyway_version")
    implementation("org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql:$flyway_version") // flyway_version=8.5.13
    implementation("mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.33")
```

the resulting error is next

```
(FlywayException: Version may only contain 0..9 and . (dot). Invalid version: 1.create.users.table) at org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion.toBigInteger:271
```

Comment: I know you have figured it out, but to add, if you upgrade the flyway version to latest, they have added a logger here, which will mention that some migrations were detected and it wasn't run. After setting the `validateMigrationNaming` to true, you can find out which all migration files were not run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay so it was dummy error in naming of migration class
I had

```
V1_create_users_table
```

and it should have been with 2 _

```
V1__create__users__table
```

Comment: Only first underscore needs to be doubled, others is not.